# how to use invoke on HubProxy signalr android

Tags: java, android, signalr

I'm new to `SignalR` library and the lack of documentation on [Microsoft's website](https://www.asp.net/signalr) in `Android` doesn't really help. I'm trying to invoke a method on the server using this code:

```
mHubProxy.invoke("method", "params...").done(new Action<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void run(Void aVoid) throws Exception {

        }
    });
```

But the result from the server isn't `void` and changing `Action<Void>` to `<Object>` gives an error. **How do I get a response from `invoke` that isn't void?**

The init part:

```
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    String serverUrl = "server";
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    String SERVER_GET_TOKEN = "name";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_GET_TOKEN);
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader("Authorization", token);
        }
    };
    mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("SimpleSignalR", e.toString());
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is how you do it (Receiving result as String):

```
mHubProxy.invoke(String.class, "param1", "param2").done(new Action<String>() {
        @Override
        public void run(String aVoid) throws Exception {

        }
    });
```